# Is it possible to render raw fluid markup without evaluating it?

Tags: typo3, fluid

I try to write a viewhelper, that outputs fluid markup in its raw format (showcase purpose for developers).

I want to do something like:

```xml
<f:showcase>
<p>
  <f:link.page pageUid="1">Link</f:link.page>
</p>
</f:showcase>
```

that should output both the rendered version and the raw input

desired viewhelper output:

```xml
Raw:
<pre class="showcase">
&lt;p&gt;
  &lt;f:link.page pageUid="1"&gt;Link&lt;/f:link.page&gt;
&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/pre&gt;
</pre>

Output:
<p>
  <a href="/site">Link</a>
</p>
```

It seems to be impossible to avoid child markup of some node being rendered by fluid. Has someone done this before or do i just miss some very obvious option to achieve this?

I found some resource about "passthrough" / {parsing off} but solving this in a pure file-based approach and moving all code examples/snippets to separate partials is not an option for me.

Is there some API in the viewhelpers to access the actual source content passed to it? I cant find any...

Alternatively i could in theory pass in non-fluid markup and generate the fluid snippet inside the viewhelper but that would be a very dirty workaround... something like the following:

```xml
<f:showcase>
<p>
  <f::link.page pageUid="1">Link</f::link.page>
</p>
</f:showcase>
```

Update: This seems to be impossible due to the file-based template processing of fluid. There is no actual src reference available in a compiled template, the only solution would be to move every snippet to a separate partial and disable the fluid parsing completely withing that partial.

So i opened an issue in the typo3fluid project:
https://github.com/TYPO3/Fluid/issues/557

I hope it gets some attention, so this might be possible sometime in the future.

Comment: not really sure if that helps, but have you tried the <f:format.raw> ViewHelper?

Comment: Yes it still parses the node content.  But thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

You used to be able to use `<[!CDATA ... ]]>` for that, but that doesn't work anymore. I think the only way to do this is to place part of the code in `<f:format.raw value="..."/>`, like:

```
<f:showcase>
<p>
  <f:format.raw value="<"/>f:link.page pageUid="1">Link</f:link.page>
</p>
</f:showcase>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be I guess to do it like in the styleguide extension

```html
    <div class="example code"><pre><code class="language-html">&lt;f:be.infobox title="Message title" state="-2"&gt;Your infobox content&lt;/f:be.infobox&gt;</code></pre></div>
```

https://github.com/TYPO3/styleguide/blob/master/Resources/Private/Templates/Backend/Infobox.html

Answer (score 0):

Fluid 3.0 supports this use case, see for example https://github.com/NamelessCoder/fluid-3-demo.

Fluid 2.x and earlier do not support this use case.

Neither version provides a way for a ViewHelper to access the raw source. Fluid 3.0 however does provide a way for a ViewHelper to take over the sequencing (iteration of template bytes) of child content, letting you collect the nested source code byte by byte (this is the mechanism that allows a ViewHelper to pass-through as seen in the link above).